# Как отсортировать массив объектов и по свойству и по имени одновременно, не создавая новых объектов?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, сортировка

Дано:
Список объектов, содержащий разные свойства, пример объекта:

```
  {
    type: 'point',
    name: 'abc',
  }
```

Мне нужно отсортировать все объекты так, чтобы сначала были с типом point по алфавиту, а потом все остальные, тоже по алфавиту. Должно получится примерно следующее:

```
{
  type: 'point',
  name: 'abc',
},{
  type: 'point',
  name: 'bcd',
}, {
  type: 'other',
  name: 'abc',
}, {
  type: 'other',
  name: 'def'
}
```

Как сортировать по имени\признаку отдельно - мне понятно. Задачу можно решить созданием 2 новых списков, в первый войдут все по типу и сортируются по алфавиту, вторые все остальные, которые тоже сортируются по алфавиту. А затем склеить эти два списка.

**Но можно ли сделать это в одной функции сортировки? Или хотя бы за два прогона, но без создания+склеивания новых массивов.**

На данный момент проблема частично решается так:

```
list.sort( (a,b) => {
 if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
 if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
 return 0;
});

list.sort( (a,b) => {
 if (a.type === 'point') return -1;
 if (b.type === 'point && a.type !== 'point) return 0;
 return 1;
});
```

Таким образом, список объектов будет отсортирован сначала по типу, а оставшиеся по алфавиту. Но те, что по типу, будут отсортированы в обратном порядке алфавита.
И, да, не используя es6.

Comment: В функции сравнения можно писать что угодно. Не обязательно сравнивать ровно одно поле

Comment: Попробуйте написать функцию сравнения объектов по следующей схеме: 1) сравниваем первое поле, при неравенстве - сортируем по нему 2) если первое поле у объектов равно - сравниваем второе и сортируем по нему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вам просто надо расставить приоритеты рассмотрения объектов при сортировке:

1. сначала рассматривать ситуацию, когда один из объектов имеет тип `point` - в этом случае он первый в сортировке
2. затем рассматривать ситуацию, когда оба объекта имеют тип `point` - тогда сравнивать по полю `name` и у кого имя меньше, тот первый в сортировке
3. затем рассматривать ситуацию, когда оба объекта имеют тип отличный от `point` - тогда сравнивать по полю `name` и у кого имя меньше, тот первый в сортировке

т.е. должно получиться что-то подобное:

```
list.sort( (a,b) => {
    // сначала первым приоритетом работаем с объектами типа `point`
    if (a.type === 'point && a.type !== 'point)
        return = -1;

    if (a.type !== 'point && a.type === 'point)
        return = 1;

    // если оба объекта типа `point` - сортируем по полю `name`
    if (a.type === 'point && a.type === 'point)
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);

    // все остальные объекты сортируем по полю `name`
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});
```

вообще любую сортировку такого типа можно провести с помощью одной функции сравнения

Comment: Ну, у вас логическая ошибка в п2 и 3. Они абсолютно идентичны. Потом, если мы встретили первый объект point, а второй нет, и сдвинули, то тут мы не применили никак сортировку имени. Таким образом, все объекты с типом point которые не шли друг за дружкой в списке не будут отсортированы по алфавиту. Точнее мне так казалось. Но на практике работает... спасибо

Comment: @sinneren, нет - они не идентичны - и если убрать п.2 то у вас может быть такая сортировка `{point, not point}, {point, not point} {not point, point}, {not point, not point}, {point, point}, {not point, not point},` вроде как, но может вы и правы - в общем это можно проверить тестом :)

Comment: так если Хоть один равен, а другой - нет, то выполняется первые 2 if. Если все равны или все не равны, то выполняется одно и то же действие. Потому и одинаковы. Мне куда непонятнее, почему сортируется правильно по алфавиту, когда мы двигаем только по первым ифам, то есть только по признаку point\не point, ведь до следующего return он просто не дойдёт, где уже по алфавиту пытаемся сортировать... Хотя, это решится второй такой же сортировкой, даже если возникнут проблемы.

Comment: @sinneren, да, да, виноват, п.2 можно опустить, это я что-то перемудрил :) оставим его для случая когда надо по `name` в одну сторону отсортировать, а п.3 - в другую :) тогда он нужен был бы, а так - можно убрать